# Banach manifold structure on the moduli space of hybrid trajectories

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, symplectic-topology, floer-homology, banach-manifold

I am reading the paper *"On the Floer homology of cotangent bundles"*, [(arXiv link)](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408280) , by Abbondandolo and Schwarz and in page $35$ to define the isomorphism between the Morse complex and the Floer complex we will wanna look into the moduli space consisting of maps such that , for $r\in ]2,4]$:
$$u\in C^{\infty}(]0,\infty[\times S^1,T^*M)\cap W^{1,r}(]0,1[\times S^1,T^*M)$$
$$\partial_su-J(t,u)(\partial_tu-X_H(t,u))=0, (s,t)\in \mathopen]0,\infty\mathclose[\times S^1$$
$$\pi^*(u(0,t))\in W^u(q;\mathcal{E},g)$$
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}u(s,t)=x(t)$$

where $\mathcal{E}$ is the lagrangian action functional, $q$ is a critical point of $\mathcal{E}$ and $x$ is a critical point of the hamiltonian action functional that is the Fenchel dual of the Lagrangian.

Now the next goal is to see that these moduli space $\mathcal{M}(q,x)$ is a Banach manifold of dimension $m(q)-\mu(x)$.

The first idea would be to consider charts of the form $exp_u(Y)$, where $u$ has the desired boundary conditions and $Y\in W^{1,r}(u^*(TT^*M))$ is such that $d\pi(Y(0,\cdot)\in W^u(q)$(this is motivated by what we do next).

But then I have the problem of seeing that $\exp_{u(0,t)}Y(0,t)\in W^u(q)$, and I am not sure if this is true or if I can even check it.

Here is another attempt, however I don't think this tells me much about the charts I am using for the submanifold since we are using the regular value theorem.
Now to do so one will see it has the pre-image of zero of a smooth map between Banach manifolds.
Therefore, my goal now is to see that the set of maps such that
$$u\in C^{\infty}(]0,\infty[\times S^1,T^*M)\cap W^{1,r}(]0,1[\times S^1,T^*M)$$
$$\pi^*(u(0,t))\in W^u(q;\mathcal{E},g)$$
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}u(s,t)=x(t)$$
can be given the structure of a Banach manifold.  Now in Floer theory one does this for the set of maps satisfying

$$u\in C^{\infty}(]0,\infty[\times S^1,T^*M)\cap W^{1,r}(]0,1[\times S^1,T^*M)$$
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow \infty}u(s,t)=x(t)$$

by using the exponential map and the Banach space $W^{1,r}(u^*(TT^*M))$, for $r\in [2,4[$. Let's call this Banach manifold $\mathcal{P}^{1,r}$. Now I want to see that the extra condition with the unstable manifold gives us a Banach submanifold. For this first recall that there is a smooth injective immersion $F^{u}:E^u\rightarrow W^{u}(q)$, and therefore we can define the smooth map

$$\phi:\mathcal{P}^{1,r}\times E^{u}\rightarrow W^{1-1/r,r}(]0,1[,T^*M)$$
$$(w,v)\rightarrow \pi(w(0,\cdot))-F^{u}(v)$$

Notice that the space $W^{1-1/r,r}(]0,1[,T^*M)$ can be given the structure of a Banach manifold, analogously to what is done for $W^{1,2}$, since we have analogous Sobolev embeddings.

Therefore our desired set if the pre-image of zero by $\phi$. The differential of this map is

$$d\phi(w,v)(\xi,\eta)\mapsto d\pi(\xi(0,\cdot))-dF^{u}(v)(\eta)$$

and hence it will be surjective. Moreover, since the unstable space is complemented, he have that the $\ker$ of differential will be complemented. Therefore we have that $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold of $\mathcal{P}^{1,r}\times E^{u}$. Now consider the projection

$$\pi_1:\mathcal{P}^{1,r}\times E^{u}\rightarrow \mathcal{P}^{1,r}$$

We have that this is an embedding if we restrict it to $\phi^{-1}(0)$, therefore our desired set, which is $\pi_1(\phi^{-1}(0))$ is a submanifold of $\mathcal{P}^{1,r}$.

I wanted to know what other people think about this approach, if this is correct, if I am making some mistake or if there is another way of seeing that this hybrid moduli space is in fact a Banach manifold.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.